# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to boot on Dell Inspiron 15-3552

Tags: boot, xorg, dell, intel-graphics, wayland

Having a blank screen after grub. Able to boot with nomodeset. `journalctl -b-1` shows session before failed session. I think this is not backlight problem. I also tried to play sound on hotkey and it didn't work. Neither `osi_acpi=`.

Having nomodeset, system boots but I get X session and software rasterizer llvmpipe.

My questions are:

- am I able to see any log before kernel ring buffer is flushed to `/var/log/kern.log` (this log doesn't seem to contain any messages from failed boot, so I suppose that the fail happens earlier)
- am I having X session because wayland does not work with nomodeset? I have read some comments that the Wayland should not work without kms.
- If I'm stuck with nomodeset and Xorg, can it be possible to setup Xorg to use the intel graphics driver? (I have read the comment that intel video driver does not work without kms somewhere in the internet, is it possible true?)

P.S.: this laptop comes with preinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 but it failed to open user session after software updates.

P.P.S.: I'm some kind of new to linux troubleshooting so I please to leave comment on what additional info and how should be retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

After many (many) attempts, what worked for me was:

1. Switching startup mode from UEFI to legacy and
2. Setting /etc/default/grub to "quiet nosplash"

More details:

1. boot, press F2 to enter Setup, go to Boot / UEFI mode: legacy
2. boot from a live usb, mount main disk, edit /media/ubuntu/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx/etc/default/grub, set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash"

This way a Dell Inspiron 3552 did boot into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Edit: after a few restarts, the problem ensisted, so I had to use "nomodeset"